# Unable to get type of object property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is that possible to get the type of object property if that object is contained in table?

```
const data = [{
  prop1: 123,
  prop2: "fgdgfdg",
}, {
  prop1: 6563,
  prop2: "dfhvcfgj",
}]

const getValuesOfProp = <ROW extends object>(key: keyof ROW, input: ROW[]): ROW[keyof ROW][] => {
  return input.map((item) => {
    return item[key]
  })
}

const result = getValuesOfProp('prop2', data)
```

The type of the result is `Array<string | number>` but should be `Array<string>`.

This is example from more complicated case: what I want to have is typed value as number in CellContent. Type should be got from 'key2' in object contained in data array.

`<Table headers={[{id: 'key2', Cell: (value) => <CellContent value={value} />}]} data={[{ key1: 'dsgfg', key2: 123}, {key1: 'dsgdfg', key2: 4356}]} />`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add second generic parameter for your `key`:

```
const getValuesOfProp = <ROW extends object, TKey extends keyof ROW>(key: TKey, input: ROW[]): ROW[TKey][] => {
    return input.map((item) => {
        return item[key]
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtA3gKBjABwCcQCBGALhjICYBmAGj0JIJqoCIAzAczh678OTAL4MYufMVKUYANgCscxs2ltOcLgAsAbsF4ArYThEBdHDlCRYPAKZQAaggA2AV1sQA8lwAKrNDAAPABKngDqMLYAHlC2YHAQMCAARga2wFDiACoA0rYAnpExcQkwANYFIFwwoWEAfAAUFflUuQXiAJZgBK5QVLUYpgCU-eEYbfmmg2h1EsxE9q5EYDBdPVAAdAC2CAQNDR2xW0Mzc-j4C1BLK4e2WxjN5vgiQyYWVtAwCxCuzrDodkcLncXl8rAaAHI1DQIeJEMhXpZwBAQM5bBtnCAeA1vr8oEMANxAA)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the the key as a generic type too.

```
const getValuesOfProp = <ROW, K extends keyof ROW>(key: K, input: ROW[]): ROW[K][] => {
  return input.map((item) => {
    return item[key]
  })
}
```

If you just return `ROW[keyof ROW][]`, TypeScript will not know that this should correlate with the passed `key` property.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtA3gKBjABwCcQCBGALhjICYBmAGj0JIJqoCIAzAczh678OTAL4MYufMVKUYANgCscxs2ltOcLgAsAbsF4ArYThEBdHDlCRYPAKZQAaggA2AV1sQA8lwAKrNDAAPABKngDq4gDSMLYAHlC2YHAQMADWtgCeIFwwoWEAfAAU6RlUkeIAlmAErlBUeRimAJT14RiRpo1o%20RLMRPauRGAwVTVQAHQAtggEhYUVCZNN3b34%20P1Qg8MLtpMYJeb4Ik0mFlbQMP0Qrs6w6HaOLu5evqyFAORqNO-iiMhNQA)